# concurrent access to a file in unix

Tags: shell, concurrency, ssh

I have a script which will run on remote servers,

df_command.sh:-

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
    echo -e "No Argument passed:- Showing default disk usage\n"
    df -k > /tmp/Global_df_tmp 2>&1
    cat /tmp/Global_df_tmp
else
    df -k "$1" > /tmp/Global_df_tmp 2>&1
    cat /tmp/Global_df_tmp
fi
```

This is how i run this script:-

```
$ssh -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l group servername 'bash -s -- /some/directory' < ./df_command.sh
```

This works fine and gives me correct output in every scenario, means if user passes any valid directory it gives me disk usage of that directory and if he/she passes some invalid directory the script gives me the proper error message back.

Problem rises when more than one user starts using the script at the same time for the same server and passes two different directories

e.g

User A:-

```
$ssh -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l group servername 'bash -s -- /user_A/directory' < ./df_command.sh
```

user B:-

```
$ssh -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l group servername 'bash -s -- /user_B/directory' < ./df_command.sh
```

Now since the tmp file for the script is same(`/tmp/Global_df_tmp`), whoever starts the script first will get the correct output while the second user will get the same output as first user got.

I know one solution would be to generate random number and use that instead of hardcoded tmp file, but if 100 users will use the same script then i'll end up having huge number of temporary files on the remote servers

Any other ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution is to not use a fixed name for temporary files. One common way to do that is to use the process identifier in a suffix, like `/tmp/Global_df_tmp.$$`.

Also, if you're using `bash` you could `$RANDOM` to get a random number.

Or just use the [`mktemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html) command to create a temporary file with a randomized name.

Comment: wouldn't i have large number of temporary files on my servers if i use random file name everytime someone access it?

Comment: @Disturbed_Entity Then delete them when you're done with them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard mktemp command to generate temporary filenames:

```
# Create a tempfile (in a BSD- and Linux-friendly way) 
my_mktemp () { 
mktemp || mktemp -t my_prefix 
} 2> /dev/null 

declare -r tempfile=$(my_mktemp) || echo "Cannot create temp file" >&2

df -k > "$tempfile" 2>&1
```

Just a little explanation: the my_mktemp is a bash function (you don't need to use that, just use mktemp if you are on Linux.

The `declare -r tempfile=$(cmd)` runs the command cmd and sets it as the value of a new read-only variable called temp file.

Afterwards you can use "$tempfile" to refer to the temp file name.